# Brakeman Rails security scanner: how to add our own custom check

Tags: ruby-on-rails, brakeman

I am using Rails security scanner [Brakeman](http://brakemanscanner.org/docs/) but I want to include my own(custom) security checks. Just like CheckSQL,CheckCrossSiteScripting
Eg: I want to make sure all the controllers has before filter to validate authentication and authorization checks.

Question
Is there a option in brakeman to include our own custom checks ?
If yes how to do it ?

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be lack of documentation on how to write custom rules. Though, you can write your own rules using existing as a reference:

https://github.com/presidentbeef/brakeman/tree/master/lib/brakeman/checks

For example, this one iterates over every controller in the project and checks them for certain vulnerability:

https://github.com/presidentbeef/brakeman/blob/35bc224ac9207670e4a448277e6a11745a6b7ef3/lib/brakeman/checks/check_basic_auth.rb

You could rewrite the method to check for before_filter instead.

Answer (score 1):

EugZol is correct, there is no documentation around writing your own checks.

I would recommend looking at [CheckSkipBeforeFilter](https://github.com/presidentbeef/brakeman/blob/master/lib/brakeman/checks/check_skip_before_filter.rb) to get an idea of how to implement a check that looks at filters.

The main things are:

- Inherit from `Brakeman::BaseCheck`
- Call `Brakeman::Checks.add self`
- Implement `run_check` method
- Use `--add-checks-path` to point Brakeman at your check directory
- Add a new warning code to `Brakeman::WarningCodes::Codes` that is > 1000 (optional)

One caveat:

Code on the master branch is significantly different from the last release and that affects the checks (hopefully makes them easier to write). So if you write a new check, you may wish to run against master. Or wait for 3.1.